# Render an element within double curly brackets {{ }} in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to do the following:

```
{{ limit_by===4 ? '<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Visa fler...' : 'Visa färre' }}
```

However Vue does not accept that i add another element `<i>` inside the {{ }}. How do I get around this? `\<i` does not work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `v-if` and `v-else` as follows:

```js
new Vue({
     el: '#app',
     data(){
          return{
               limit_by:4
          }
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<div id="app">
     <p v-if="limit_by===4">
          <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Visa fler...
     </p>
     <p v-else>
          Visa färre
     </p>
</div>
```

You can check the [docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use conditional rendering with `v-if` and `v-else` directives :

```html
<template v-if="limit_by===4">
   <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Visa fler...
</template>
<template v-else>
   Visa färre
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is important to note that the use of double mustaches interprets the data as plain text, not html. I'm paraphrasing here but check out the `v-html` directive that is packaged with Vue on this [page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML).

Using the `v-html` directive means you could still maintain the use of your ternary statement as follows:

```
<div v-html="limit_by===4 ? '<i class="fas fa-plus"></i>Visa fler...' : 'Visa färre'"></div>
```